# What is better way to compute percentage from numeric result of two SQL queries

Tags: oracle11g

I have two oracle(11g) SQL queries that give one numeric result each.

SQL1:

```
select count(*) as count1 
  from table_name1
 where col1_number in (2400)
   and (col2_varchar2 = '' or col2_varchar2 is null or col2_varchar2 = 'BLANK' or 
        col2_varchar2 = 'TBA' or col2_varchar2 like 'B%')
   and col3_varchar2 = 'app31'
   and col4_date > (sysdate - 7)
```

SQL2:

```
select count(*) as count2 
  from table_name1
 where col1_number in (2400)
   and col3_varchar2 = 'app31'
   and col4_date > (sysdate - 7)
```

Lets say I get 35 as result from SQL1 and 831 as result from SQL2. Then I want to write a SQL which will take these two result from SQL1 and SQL2 and compute (35 * 100)/831.

I have written one SQL that will do this.

SQL3:

```
select round((count1 * 100)/count2,3) as percent_missing from
(
with temp_table1 as (
    select count(*) as count1 
      from table_name1
     where col1_number in (2400)
       and (col2_varchar2 = '' or col2_varchar2 is null or col2_varchar2 = 
            'BLANK' or col2_varchar2 = 'TBA' or col2_varchar2 like 'B%')
       and col3_varchar2 = 'app31'
       and col4_date > (sysdate - 7)
), 

temp_table2 as (
    select count(*) as count2 
      from table_name1
     where col1_number in (2400)
       and col3_varchar2 = 'app31'
       and col4_date > (sysdate - 7)
) 
select count1, count2 
  from temp_table1, temp_table2
);
```

**Question:** Is there any better way to do this? I want to know if there is any other/better way which is recommended in such scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see both SQL1 and SQL2 uses same table and almost same where clause except an extra AND condition in SQL1 so why don't we just consolidate them like below:

```
select round((a.count1 * 100)/a.count2,3) as percent_missing from (
    select count(case when (col2_varchar2 = '' or col2_varchar2 is null or col2_varchar2 = 
                'BLANK' or col2_varchar2 = 'TBA' or col2_varchar2 like 'B%') then 1 end ) as count1, 
                count(1) as count2 
            from table_name1 where
                col1_number in (2400) and 
                and col3_varchar2 = 'app31'
                and col4_date > (sysdate - 7)
    ) as a
```

I could not test this as I don't tables and their schema please forgive me for the compilation error but you will get idea here.

Comment: Thank you for your response, after removing repeated "and" and "as" your suggested SQL works same way as SQL3. And it looks cleaner so I am going to use this version.